# PDO: Prevent value overwrite if UPDATE :column and WHERE :column is the same

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a function that binds/prepares the statement then execute it:

```
function db_update ($table, $set, $where_col, $where_val)
{
    $s = "UPDATE `$table` SET ";
    foreach ($set as $k => $v)
        $s.= "$k = :".trim($k).", ";
    $s = trim($s, ', ');
    $s.= " WHERE `$where_col` = :$where_col";

    $binds = array();
    foreach ($set as $k => $v)
        $binds[':'.$k] = trim($v);
    $binds[':'.$where_col] = trim($where_val);

    return db_run($s, $binds);
}
```

Basically `db_run` does your usual PDO methods:

```
function db_run($stmt, $binds = array())
{
    // ...      
    $sth = $db->prepare($stmt);
    $sth->execute($binds);      
    // ...
}
```

**Sample usage A:**

`db_update('table', ['color' => 'red'], 'fruit', 'apple');`

**Result:**

- Prepared: `UPDATE table SET color = :color WHERE fruit = :fruit`
- Actual: `UPDATE table SET color = 'red' WHERE fruit = 'apple'`

This runs just fine, but my main issue is what if the usage is like  this:

**Sample usage B:**

`db_update('table', ['color' => 'red'], 'color', 'black');`

**Result:**

- Prepared: `UPDATE table SET color = :color WHERE color = :color`
- Actual: `UPDATE table SET color = 'black' WHERE color = 'black'`

How can I make it so the actual result is:

`UPDATE table SET color = 'red' WHERE color = 'black'`

Comment: I'd say just have a `:whereColor`

Comment: @PatrickQ You mean change the table structure (column name)?

Comment: No, you're going to need to update your `db_update()` function though.  I'll write up an answer, but honestly, I'm not sure how much real-world mileage you're going to get out of a function like that.  I know I sure wouldn't have much use for it.

Comment: @PatrickQ Just to comment about real world mileage, the above sample function is just a simplified chunk of a bigger query builder class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that result because you're using the `:color` parameter in both places (the SET and the WHERE) in your query.  So your `db_update()` function needs to use a different parameter name for the WHERE clause.

```
function db_update ($table, $set, $where_col, $where_val)
{
    $s = "UPDATE `$table` SET ";
    foreach ($set as $k => $v)
        $s.= "$k = :".trim($k).", ";
    $s = trim($s, ', ');
    $s.= " WHERE `$where_col` = :where_$where_col";

    $binds = array();
    foreach ($set as $k => $v)
        $binds[':'.$k] = trim($v);
    $binds[':where_'.$where_col] = trim($where_val);

    return db_run($s, $binds);
}
```

This should result in a prepared result of `UPDATE table SET color = :color WHERE color = :where_color`

Comment: That works. All this time I didn't know :named_parameters could be named after anything. I always thought they should be the same as column name!

Comment: Glad to help.  Just know that this function is going to have limitations as you currently only allow one `WHERE` condition, and you wouldn't be able to update on column based on the value of another, etc.

Comment: You are right, this is just a sample function for simplicity. The actual query builder class can do multi `where`